# Set of tuples, how to find a tuple containing a given number

Tags: set, tuples

I know it takes O(1) time to check if given number is in a set. My question is  if I have a set of tuples, can I check in O(1) time if some number belongs to some tuple, and then return the tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity would depend on your implementation.

Say you have an array of tuples. In your question, if you know *which* tuple to search in, then the complexity is `O(1)` as you directly index the known tuple and then complete your query.

However, if you must iterate through all tuples in the array set to find the one of interest, then the complexity may be `O(n)` or `O(n lg n)` depending on your search implementation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, that's why I was thinking that maybe there is some implementation with  sets instead of lists. Maybe not?

Comment: Use of sets vs. lists is language dependent. Regardless, you'll have increased complexity for any required iteration to resolve a query where an index is unknown.